# How to get the data from a dummy API and display it using AG grid in angular

Tags: angular, pagination, ag-grid

I'm trying to display the data from API and display it using AG grid in angular. I'm using [API using to get the data.](https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users) . But I'm getting an error "t. map is not a function at o.setRowData" in my application. In stack blitz, data is not displaying. Kindly help me in displaying the data by looking into my example.[stack blitz example. please find here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-33jfxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Check this how to ask question in better way [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make below changes in your code:

> HTML: You are getting `Observable` in response so you will have to use `async` operator with it.

```
[rowData]="rowData | async"
```

> TS: Your API is returning two keys 'meta' and 'data', so you will have to map it correctly

```
this.rowData = this.http.get<any[]>('https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users')
.pipe(
  map(res => res.data)
);
```

Link to [stackblitz](https://ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-fudzch.stackblitz.io)